# BigQuery GUI - CPU Resource Limit

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to set the CPU Resource Limit on the BigQuery with Python and GUI?

I'm getting an error of:

```
Query exceeded resource limits. 2147706.163729571 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 46300.0 CPU seconds.
```

Looking at the BigQuery's Python reference page: http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/reference.html

It looks like there's:

```
1. maximum_billing_tier
2. maximum_bytes_billed
```

That can be set, but there is no CPU second options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set anymore `maximum_billing_tier` - it is obsolete and as soon as you are lower than tier 100 you are billed as if it were 1. if you exceed 100 - query just failes.

As of CPU - check concept of [`slots`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots)

> Maximum concurrent slots per project for on-demand pricing — 2,000
>   The default number of slots for on-demand queries is shared among all queries in a single project. As a rule, if you're processing less than 100 GB of queries at once, you're unlikely to be using all 2,000 slots.
>
> To check how many slots you're using, see Monitoring BigQuery Using Stackdriver. If you need more than 2,000 slots, contact your sales representative to discuss whether flat-rate pricing meets your needs.

See more at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs

Comment: Is there a way to check how large the datasets are?

Comment: you mean size-wise?

Comment: Yep, for example if my I add up the amount of GBs in all the datasets I'm using from the "FROM" keyword. I'm wondering if that would give me a good idea how many concurrent slots I might be using before running a query.

Comment: you can see size of any table in BigQuery UI - select table and see Details for that table. Also when you construct the query in BQ UI, you can see estimated number of bytes to be scanned by that query. And, also you can use API to check how much data will be used by using so called `Dry Run`

Comment: Thanks! I know how to proceed now.